# Comparing differences between calculated areas of multiple shapefile by using PyQGIS and geopandas python module

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7, geopandas

I have calculated area of multiple shapefile by using PyQGIS and geopandas python module but results are not same. Which one is better?

logic in QGIS:

```
with edit(eligibleLayer):
    for gFeat in eligibleLayer.getFeatures():

        area = QgsDistanceArea()
        area.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
        area.setEllipsoidalMode(True)
        area.computeAreaInit()

        geom = gFeat.geometry()
        print("Feature ID %d: " % gFeat.id())
        attrs = gFeat.attributes()

        multiPart = gFeat.geometry().isMultipart()

        if (multiPart is False):
            pol = gFeat.geometry().asPolygon()
            print("glac_name"+attrs[14]+'-'+"area is %.2f km2" % (area.measurePolygon(pol[0])/1e6))
        else:
            pol = gFeat.geometry().asMultiPolygon()
            print("There are %d polygons" % len(pol))
            i=1
            for geom in pol:
                print("area%d is %.2f km2") % (i, area.measurePolygon(geom[0])/1e6)
                i +=1
```

GeoPandas with python:

```
fp = gpd.read_file('/home/priya/project/EAST/data/east_him.shp')

a = fp.crs
tost = fp.copy()

tost = tost.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})
b = tost.crs
print(b)

tost["su_area"] = tost['geometry'].area / 10**6
tost.head()
```

Comment: probably the computation in the projected coordinate system

Comment: How do you define "better"?  What result did you get from each method?